# Bootstrap navbar fixed on scroll overlapped by content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scroll, z-index, navbar

I have a navbar which is fixed to the top after the user scrolls down on the page. The problem is that the navbar is behind the content as seen on the image below. After scroll I'm adding a class to the navbar '.scrolled'. Thanks

[navbar under the content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3KZG.png)

```css
.land-header-cont {
  img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.15;
  }
  nav {
    transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    @media screen and (min-width: 768px){
      padding-top: 50px;
    }
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 0;
    font-family: 'Raleway' , 'Roboto', sans-serif !important;
    .remotey-left {
      .remotey-text {
        font-size: 1.5em;
      }
      i {
        font-size: 1.5em;
        &.white-bg {
          color: #22262F;
          background-color: #f0f0f0;
          padding-bottom: 2px;
          padding-left: 3px;
          padding-right: 2px;
          border-radius: 3px;
          margin-right: 3px;
        }
        &.small {
          font-size: 1.1em;
          margin-right: 5px;
        }
      }
      a {
        padding-top: 5px;
      }
    }
    .navbar-nav {
      li {
        a {
          color: white;
        }
        &:hover {
          a {
            color: #bb77ff;
            font-size: bold;
          }
        }
      }
      .btn-transparent {
        margin-top: -7px;
        height: 35px;
        width: 100%;
        padding-top: 7px;
        &.pink {
          border-color: #bb77ff;
          color: #bb77ff;
          &:hover {
            background-color: #bb77ff;
            color: white;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    &.scrolled {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 9999999;
      padding-top: 10px;
      background-color: white;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
      li {
        a {
          color: #202020
        }
      }
      min-height: 65px !important;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      .remotey-left {
        margin-top: 7px;
      }
      .land-content {
        padding-top: 80px;
      }
    }
  }
  min-height: 70vh;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #22262F;
  opacity: 0.9;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  .content-header {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    h1 {
      letter-spacing: 0.05em;
      .pink {
        color: #bb77ff;
      }
    }
    .full {
      border-color: #bb77ff;
      background-color: #bb77ff;
      color: white;
      @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
        width: 20%;
      }
      padding: 6px;
      height: 35px;
    }
    .bottom-arrow {
      border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
      border-radius: 50%;
      width: 70px;
      height: 70px;
      margin: 50px auto;
    }
  }
}

.land-content {
  background-color: white;
  img {
    z-index: -1;
  }
}
```

```html
<body class="fixed-nav">

<div class="container-fluid land-header-cont">
    <img src="img/landing_header_bg.jpg" class="">
    <!--<div class="content">-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav remotey-left hidden-xs">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-rlogo white-bg"></i><span class="remotey-text">remotey</span>  </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-facebook-counter small"></i><span class="">Share</span>  </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-twitter-counter small"></i><span class="">Tweet</span>  </a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#">VACANCIES</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">TASKS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ENTERPRISE</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">POST JOB</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
                        <li><a href="login.html">LOGIN</a></li>
                        <li><a href="signup.html"><div class="btn btn-transparent pink">SIGN UP FOR FREE</div> </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
    <!--</div>-->
    <div class="container content-header content" style="padding-top: 200px;">
        <h1>Find your new <span class="pink">remote job</span> with Remotey</h1>
        <h4 style="padding-top: 50px; letter-spacing: 0.05em; font-weight: 100">The marketplace where anything is possible</h4>
        <a href="#"><div class="btn btn-transparent pink full">GET STARTED - FREE!</div></a>
        <a href="#">
            <div class="bottom-arrow">
                <i class="icon-arrowdown-2x"></i>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid land-content">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <h3>Remote vacancies from all around the world</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <img src="img/l1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid land-content">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <h3>Remote vacancies from all around the world</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <img src="img/l1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid land-content">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <h3>Remote vacancies from all around the world</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <img src="img/l1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
</div>

<script src="./js/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="./js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="./js/material.js"></script>
<script src="./js/ripples.js"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery.dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="./js/main_index.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.material.init();
        var header_h = $('.land-header-cont').outerHeight();
        console.log(header_h);
        $(window).scroll(function (event) {
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (scroll > header_h) {
                $('.navbar-default').addClass('scrolled');
                $('.land-content').css('padding-top','80px');
            } else {
                if ($('.navbar-default').hasClass('scrolled')) {
                    $('.navbar-default').removeClass('scrolled');
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and adding a z-index to different parts of the nav. Also try and create a wrapper div and give that wrapper a large z-index.

Comment: that is the problem that a small z-index on the content (like -3) doesn't work even when the navbar has a massive z-index like 1300